# How to make a one website for all devices, PC, iphone, blackberry, windows mobile android etc?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to make one website for all PC, IPhone, Blackberry, Windows Mobile (IE Mobile), Opera Mobile Browser etc.

What thing need consider, avoid. I know Javascript is not much supported by mobile browsers and CSS media handheld is not supported by IPhone.

Comment: I think you're looking for a grail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create at least two types website, one for desktop browser and one for mobile browser. For desktop browser i think you might be know that all most all modern browsers have no problem with rendering standard ACID 2 (i didn't know why IE8 keep failing on some sites, since it fully support ACID 2).

Mobile browser generally support HTML 4, and XHTML 1.0 Basic, you may consider what DOCTYPE you will use based on browser support... as far as i create mobile website, i use XHTML 1.0 Basic and WCSS (some sort CSS extension for mobile browser).

So far Opera has been the best on Mobile Browser, followed by IPhone Safari, Pocket IE was the worse and Blackberry browser was too old (except for new devices such as Storm).

Things to avoid usually Javascript and CSS 2 (better stick with CSS 1.x) don't use too much CSS especially positioning & border

And i suggest you to read some article at http://mobiforge.com/

EDIT (add more reference article):
for mobile web design you should check some article like below:
http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/effective-design-multiple-screen-sizes
http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/mobile-app-design-getting-point-part-i

Comment: so we can't make a good single website for all devices. 2 separate website with 2 different url is a good option . but 2 different url is hard to remember than one.

Comment: why not make something simple? example google has done m.google.com or yahoo with m.yahoo.com for mobile website, is it too hard for creating subdomain m.yourdomain.com for example? or maybe you could register your domain at dotMobi so you can use yourdomain.mobi

Comment: btw you can create 1 url to rule all, but you must use what so called device detection schema so your website can detect whether the client is from Desktop PC or Mobile Devices

Comment: Thx for your all suggestion it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.phonegap.com

Comment: This is awesome!!!
They also have a jquery like library called XUI that is very small. 2.5k minified.

Comment: I love phonegap, but it helps you build native apps in javascript and HTML. It does not help you make a web site that renders well on mobile platforms. You need other tools for that. (Other tools that go well with phonegap, if you're building a native app.)

Answer (score 1):

Try these guys:

http://www.wapple.net

They have an online program which renders your website out perfectly to the abilities of each handset.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question as you do! But you can't make a mobile and pc site. You could have something like: www.yoursite.com and a mobile named www.m.yoursite.com, something like that. But I know  a few things that you should not put in your mobile site.
•Flash～Flash videos,(Youtube)Flash Games/Animations(*.swf)...should not be in your mobile site!
•Javascript～Most devices can't handle some Javascript. (With the acception of Opera 9.5 for the Nintendo DSi.)Yet sites for the DSi use Javascript for everything. (Such as www.dsipaint.com and www.dsicade.com)
•BIG PICTURES!～If you put in large pictures the page may not load correctly.
•Lots ah' Content～This is just like big pictures. But too much content may make a error screen pop up that says something like this: “The page contains too much content. Returning to the home page.”
Just remember some of my tips!
(If you need an example of a good mobile site try: hachibook.muf.mobi on your mobile browser.)

Answer (score 0):

any platform that supports xhtml

Answer (score 0):

By using css you can have a one page and two style one for pc and one for mobile 
For making this situation follow this step
1 make page
2 styling for pc in for example a.css
3 styling for mobile in for example b.css
4 in  tag create link to both css file but for the pc one add media attribute and fill it content by ="screen" and for mobile ="handheld"